# "this" is not recognizing in react's input for getting value

Tags: html, reactjs, input, this, undefined

I never understood how that this works if it ever works
in my react I wrote `<input onChange={()=>console.log(this.value)} />` Why doesn't it recognize this??? it tells me that it Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
onChange anyone help please :/

Comment: React doesn't bind the function with the input element when calling it, so you'll need a reference to it. See `React.createRef()`: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: (e)=>e.target.value is better I guess but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React doesn't bind the event listener with the element.
So, the `this` refers to the class  Component in which its defined. 
If it was in functional Component then `this` it `undefined`

So if your trying to read input elements value use this,

```
<input onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} />
```

Read More,
[Function And Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Comment: Yeah that's it my friend advised me also but i forgot to delete lol thanks